# Disable chrome user agent stylesheet * selector for SVGs?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, profiling

I noticed recently that Chrome applies the following CSS rule to all SVG elements (regardless of how they are embedded [object, embed, iframe, or inline]):

```
* {
  -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin-z: initial;
}
```

Running the CSS selector profiler, the * selector is by far the biggest performance hit. This appears to cause scrolling, etc to feel sluggish with several very complex SVGs in a page.

My question is: how can I get around this? Is there any way to **delete** this rule (not override, because in this case that would cause selector performance to be *worse*)?

Perhaps this was an oversight by the Chrome team, or maybe it's there for reasons I don't understand (bonus points to anyone who can also explain *why* it's there and if I'm wrong to want it gone).

Perhaps also I'm reading the profiler incorrectly. Here's a screenshot (irrelevant selectors removed).

[image: * selector in Chrome CSS profiler]

I know I'm asking a lot of questions here, but is there a reason (other than it simply hasn't been implemented yet) why the "Source" column is not populated?

Comment: Are you certain the sluggishness is because of the selector and not because Chrome is slow when it comes to rendering SVGs?

Comment: Not at all. It could just be that, but I have no way to test, since I can't disable the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: You imply that the selector is only targeting SVGs, but that's not possible.  Judging from the purpose of transform-origin (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin), it seems appropriate to have a logical default state on every element.

Comment: It's only applied within the SVG doc. So only on SVG elements.

Answer (score 2):

The `Source` column is not populated, because there are no source files for the particular rules listed in the profile. This is due to the rules residing in the user agent stylesheet, which is sort of "hardcoded" into the Chrome code, and does not correspond to an actual resource.

Now, try switching to absolute times (the `%` button in the status bar below the profile view) and see how much time in milliseconds it actually takes. I bet you will be surprised unless you are viewing an HTML5 spec as a single page.

As far as I know, `-webkit-transform-origin` is used this way to enforce hardware-accelerated compositing for the entire page.

Comment: The source column is not populated even for my own style rules (which I've removed in the image, but I can assure you are there).

Comment: Ack, thanks for reporting... https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104225 filed.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the rule to HTML only by using namespaces, at least in XHTML (not sure for "normal" HTML):

```
@namespace html 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
html|* {
  -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin-z: initial;
}
```

(Compare another example on [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/vmWNUPjS)).

For "normal" HTML, using a `not()` selector with the SVG namespace should work:

```
@namespace svg 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
*:not(svg|*) {
  -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin-z: initial;
}
```

I'm not sure, though, whether this would improve performance.

Comment: I don't think this helps, because I don't have access to the user-agent stylesheet that Chrome is applying to SVGs. If I apply this rule in my own stylesheet, it doesn't seem to make a difference.